# FME: how to extract the coordinate of the North West corner

Tags: geoprocessing, coordinates, fme-form, coordinate-system, spatial-etl

In an FME translation from a polygon geodatabase feature class to a DGN I am trying to place a label in the top left corner of a box. I have tried using CoordinateExtractor to find the coordinates of a corner (then 2DPointReplacer and TexAdder to add text to this coordinate) but this works on the number of the vertex, which unfortunately isn't constant as not all of my boxes are quadrilateral. What I need to find is a way to find the upper left vertex. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are almost there:
If you post your workspace (or screenshot would be easier to follow)

What I think you are missing is the BoundsExtractor for your polygon (rather than the vertices)

[image]

http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/boundsextractor.htm

*2014 FME Desktop used here (looks different to 2013)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. The only problem this leaves me with are (rare) oddly shaped boxes. Do you know of a transformer that finds the nearest vertex to a point?

Comment: Try the NeighborFinder. In the attributes it adds will be the nearest coordinate with distance and bearing too